# How can I cleanly monkey patch a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Having a low level C/assembly programming background, one thing I was wondering is whether it is possible in Javascript to *detour* a function, meaning, replacing it with a function that I defined and then call the original one, to add additional code or hook that function.
I already found examples, but all of them are not what I would qualify *clean*, involve creating additional variables, etc

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Monkey patching in Javascript is used heavily by many frameworks jusk like **zone.js** patch **async operations** (For angular).

**Solution 1:** Simplest way monkey patching can be used is as follows.

```
var orig_setTimeout = window.setTimeout;

window.setTimeout = function setTimeout(fn, ms) {
    // your patching code goes here
    return orig_setTimeout(fn, ms);
}
```

**Solution 2:** Using **IIFE**.

Credit **@Annihil** [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945683/how-can-i-cleanly-monkey-patch-a-function-in-javascript/52945922#52945922)

```
function originalFn(arg){
    return console.log("originalFn is invoked with argument: " + arg);
}

var patchedFn = (function(originalFunction) {

    return function(){
        console.log("patched function is invoked with arguments: " + arguments)
        return originalFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}(originalFn))


patchedFn("Hello");

// Above invocation will results in 
patched function is invoked with arguments: Hello
originalFn is invoked with argument: Hello
```

**Solution 3:** You can use apply trap of **ES6 Proxies**

```
var patchedFn = {
  apply (target, ctx, args) {
    console.log("patched function is invoked with arguments: " + args)
    return Reflect.apply(...arguments)
  }
}
function originalFn (arg) {
    return console.log("originalFn is invoked with argument: " + arg);
}
var proxyFn = new Proxy(originalFn, patchedFn);

// Now proxy function can be invoked as following

proxyFn("Hello");
proxyFn(...["Hello"]);
proxyFn.call(null, "Hello");
proxyFn.apply(null, ["Hello"]);

// All the above invocation will print the below output

patched function is invoked with arguments: Hello
originalFn is invoked with argument: Hello
```

**Solution 4:** You can also look into **ES6 decorators**. They might also suits your purpose. For a introduction to ES6 decorators you can follow the [sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-decorators-what-they-are/)

**Case Study:**
If you wanted to understand how **zone.js patched async** operations please go through the blog post [monkey patching in zone.js](https://medium.com/reverse-engineering-angular/angular-deep-dive-zone-js-how-does-it-monkey-patches-various-apis-9cc1c7fcc321)

Comment: Thanks, but your example involve creating a temporary variable to store the original pointer function, I do not want to encumber the current scope with it...

Comment: In that case use ES6 proxies. You can use "apply" trap for the following. More details can be found at https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-proxy-traps-in-depth#apply

Comment: ES6 has a proxy feature, I didn't know that, interesting!

Comment: Hi Norel. If that solves your problem, up vote and accept the answer so that other SO users can benefit from the same. In case it doesn't, do let me know the details.