# How do you override setTimeout to provide a stack trace if the timer exceeds a certain amount?

Tags: javascript, typescript, expo

Expo has a warning that appears.

> Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
> (Saw setTimeout with duration 3601013ms)

I don't mind trying to resolve the warning as much, but the stack trace it provides does not state where teh setTimeout is called which makes it difficult to determine which module is doing it because I presume it is an external module that calls setTimeout

Is there a way of replacing setTimeout to do something like this in TypeScript?

```
global.setTimeout = 
  (f : ()=>unknown, timeout ) => { 
    if (timeout > 3600) { console.printStackTrace<?> } 
    global.setTimeout() 
  }
```

That way I know relatively where setTimeout was called so I can fix the issue.

I tried monkeypatching this way in App.js but I am still getthing the warning without my stack trace

```
// Monkeypatch setTimeout
const originalSetTimeout = setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = (fn, ms) => {
  if (ms > 3600000) {
    console.trace(`setTimeout called with ms=${ms} > 3600000`);
  }
  return originalSetTimeout(fn, ms);
};
```

Comment: create an `Error` which you can either throw or not.  e.g.:  `throw new Error('timeout too big')`

Comment: You'll need to save the original setTimeout somewhere and forward to the original.  Read how to _monkeypatch_ or _detour_ a built-in function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52945914/1563833)

Comment: `console.trace('It's here!')` will do?

Comment: @Wyck can monkeypatching be done on TypeScript cleanly?